# Spaces in Electronic band structure

Tags: quantum-espresso, band-structure, electronic-structure, bandgap, spintronics

I keep getting this whenever I try plotting the electronic band structure for CoRhMnGa on quantum Espresso, what could possibly cause the vertical spaces

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.